# JavaScript order DOM elements based on name

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, dom, sorting

So I've got a list of hidden fields:

```
<ul class="reorderable">
    <li>Foo<input class="hiddenThing" type=hidden name="thing[0]" value=foo /></li>
    <li>Bar<input class="hiddenThing" type=hidden name="thing[1]" value=bar /></li>
    <li>Baz<input class="hiddenThing" type=hidden name="thing[2]" value=baz /></li>
</ul>
```

Purely informational, I don't expect this to be related to the answer, but FYI I'm using the JQuery UI "sortable" plugin:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('ul.reorderable').sortable({ update: stuffHappens; });
}
</script>
```

The thing you need to understand from this is that the sortable plugin allows the user to reorder these elements arbitrarily. Now, what I want to do is implement a revert button.

```
<button value="Revert" onClick="revertList()" />
```

I want this to **put the elements of the list back in order based on the name of the hidden inputs**. I imagine this will require regexes (to extract the number from the brackets in the name. `thing[10]` should come after `thing[9]`) and I imagine that JQuery will be handy. But I'm drawing a blank when I try to approach this problem, probably because I'm not familiar with sorting DOM elements nor regexing with JavaScript.

Keeping this naming format is a must.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably use a standard array sort, then remove all the items and add them back sorted:

```
$('#reorder').click(function() {
    // get the list items and store references to them,
    // grabbing their names on the way
    var items = [];
    $('ul.reorderable li').each(function() {
        var name = $('input', this).attr('name'),
            // regex is overkill if you're always using the same format
            // this is quick, but a little hacky - parseInt stops
            // at non-numeric characters
            pos = parseInt(name.split("[")[1]);
        items.push({
            item: this, // store a reference to the DOM element
            pos: pos 
        });
    });
    // now sort by name
    items.sort(function(a,b) {
        return a.pos > b.pos ? 1 : -1;
    });
    // delete the items and add them back sorted
    var $ul = $('ul.reorderable');
    $ul.empty();
    // forEach() might be more elegant, but isn't cross-browser yet
    for (var x=0; x<items.length; x++) {
        $ul.append(items[x].item);
    }
});
```

Working version here: http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/Ew2EX/3/

This might get slow if you have a large number of items, but it's much easier than trying to reorder them in-place.

**Code updated** to compare single- and double-digit numbers (because `"2"` > `"11"`).

Comment: pretty good, but the string comparison doesn't capture the numeric sort I need for lists > 10. Forked example: http://jsfiddle.net/wWmA9/

Comment: Works like a charm. I ended up using a slightly different approach but using most of the same concepts from your solution, including the hacky `parseInt(name.split("[")[1])` which I thought was clever.

Answer (score 2):

```
function revertList() {
    var $ul = $('ul.reorderable'),
        $inps = $ul.find('li').find('input.hiddenThing');

    for (var i = 0, il = $inps.length; i < il; i++) {
        $inps.filter('[name="thing['+i+']"]').closest('li')
             .detach().appendTo($ul);
    }
}
```

[**Demo →**](http://jsfiddle.net/BDJaC/)

Comment: I like that approach, but it only works if you're certain to have the exact series - stick an extra `thing[22]` in and it'll break. Not sure whether the OP's use case includes this concern or not.

Comment: I was about to note the same thing. In fact, my particular use case does not include that concern; the <li>s are auto-generated and therefore the hidden element names are always sequential from 0 up.

Comment: Here's a version of @mVChr's response that works with non-sequential indexes: http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/Ew2EX/6/ . I'd go with his answer - more elegant than mine for your use case.

Comment: despite nrabinowitz's suggestion, I've accepted his answer. But +1 for this beautiful jquery-centric answer.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but it's actually very simple to sort elements once you have selected them with jQuery.

Being array-based, you can apply sorting to it using the standard `Array.prototype.sort()` method. Once the child elements have been sorted, you can append them back into the parent element without having to worry about duplicating elements; it would just work :)

To get the numeric index out of the name I've opted to simply filter out anything that's not a digit.

```js
$('.reorderable').append(function() {
  return $(this).children().sort(function(a, b) {
    var re = /\d+/,
        a_index = +a.name.match(re)[0],
        b_index = +b.name.match(re)[1];
    return a_index - b_index;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="reorderable">
    <li>Foo<input class="hiddenThing" type=hidden name="thing[2]" value=foo /></li>
    <li>Bar<input class="hiddenThing" type=hidden name="thing[1]" value=bar /></li>
    <li>Baz<input class="hiddenThing" type=hidden name="thing[0]" value=baz /></li>
</ul>
```